# Is it possible to execute Azure Test Plans using Rest api Powershell Script

Tags: powershell, azure-pipelines, rest, azure-devops-rest-api

I am new to Rest api and Powershell Scripting. I wanted to know if we can execute the Azure Test plans using Powershell script.
My plan is to write a powershell script to execute set of existing Test plans in my project. Then use that powershell script in Pipeline and schedule the pipeline to run at specific time.
Please help me.
I know that we can get list of Test Plans using Rets api , is it possible to execute them as well?

Answer (score 0):

Test Plan does not support being run, only test point can be executed.

If you want to use Rest API to execute automatic test in test plan, you could refer to the following steps:

Here are the following steps:

Step1: You could define a variable in Release Pipeline.

[image]

Step2: Add this variable in VSTest Task:

[image]

**Note:** The test run id needs to correspond to the release one-to-one, and then the status of the test run will be updated.

Here is an example:

```
param (
    [string]$token="",
    [string]$collection="",
    [string]$projectName ="",
    [int] $planIdStatic =947 ,
    [int] $suiteIdStatic =1086 ,
    [int] $testcaseID =79,
    [int] $releasedefinitionid =96,
    [int] $buildid =62903


)

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user, $token)))
$response = Invoke-RestMethod "https://dev.azure.com/$collection/$projectName/_apis/test/plans?api-version=5.0" -Method 'GET' -Headers @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
foreach( $val in $response.value)
{

#PLAN ID 
Write-Host $val.id
 # $planId = [convert]::ToInt32($val.id)
 [int] $planId = $planIdStatic
  $suites = "https://dev.azure.com/$collection/$projectName/_apis/test/plans/$planId/suites?api-version=5.0"
 $listofSuites = Invoke-RestMethod $suites -Method 'GET' -Headers @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
 #define Suite ID

 [int] $suiteId = $suiteIdStatic
 $suitename = "https://dev.azure.com/$collection/$projectName/_apis/test/plans/$planId/suites/$suiteId/points?api-version=5.0"
 $listofSuites = Invoke-RestMethod $suitename -Method 'GET' -Headers @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}


 #Define TestCaseID

 [int] $tcID = $testcaseID

 $tc = "https://dev.azure.com/$collection/$projectName/_apis/test/plans/$planId/suites/$suiteId/points?testCaseId=$tcID&api-version=5.0"
 $testcaseapi = Invoke-RestMethod $tc -Method 'GET' -Headers @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
 
 #Define PointID

[int] $pointID =    $testcaseapi.value[0].id 
 $runName = "Test RUN Setup"

 #PayLoad

 $payload = @"
 
 {
   "name":"test",
    "automated":true,
    "pointIds":[$pointID],
    "state":"NotStarted",
    "dtlTestEnvironment":{"id":"vstfs://dummy"},
    "plan":{"id":"$planId"},
    "filter":{"sourceFilter":"*.dll","testCaseFilter":""}
}
"@;

#Initiate the RUN

$tcRun = "https://dev.azure.com/$collection/$projectName/_apis/test/runs?api-version=5.0"
 $testRun = Invoke-RestMethod $tcRun -Method 'POST'  -ContentType "application/json"  -Body $payload -Headers @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} 
Write-Host "Test Run Status is ...."

$testrunid = $testRun.id

echo $testrunid


$url = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/$collection/$projectName/_apis/Release/definitions/$($releasedefinitionid)?api-version=5.0-preview.3"
Write-Host "URL: $url"
$pipeline = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get  -Headers @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} 

Write-Host "Pipeline = $($pipeline | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"


$pipeline.variables.testrunid.value = "$testrunid"

####****************** update the modified object **************************
$json = @($pipeline) | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99


$updatedef = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Put -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} 



$releaseRunurl ="https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/$collection/$projectName/_apis/Release/releases?api-version=6.1-preview.8"

 $releasebody = @"
 
 {
     "definitionId": $releasedefinitionid

}
"@;

$ReleaseRun = Invoke-RestMethod $releaseRunurl -Method 'POST'  -ContentType "application/json"  -Body $releasebody -Headers @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} 

$Releaseid=$ReleaseRun.id

echo $Releaseid

$ReleaseEnvID=$ReleaseRun.environments.id

echo $ReleaseEnvID

$updateTestrun="https://dev.azure.com/$collection/$projectName/_apis/test/Runs/$($testrunid)?api-version=6.1-preview.3"

$updatebody = @"
 
 {
    "build":
    {
        "id":"$buildid"
    },
    "releaseEnvironmentUri":"vstfs:///ReleaseManagement/Environment/$ReleaseEnvID","releaseUri":"vstfs:///ReleaseManagement/Release/$Releaseid"

}
"@;


$UpdateRun = Invoke-RestMethod $updateTestrun -Method 'PATCH'  -ContentType "application/json"  -Body $updatebody -Headers @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} 


 

}
```

**Result:**

When the release is completed, the status of the test run will be updated

[image]